# Azure build fails with "ng" unrecognized

Tags: angular, azure, deployment, kudu

I am trying to deploy angular application with azure +"kudu" .In build script It doesn't pick up "Ng keyword".

1. I have set default node version to higher one
2. angular dependencies added to dependency list as well.

i have tried almost all the solutions in the internet but cannot make this work,can someone please help me to resolve this

build script result

```
Command: deploy.cmd
D:\home\site\repository\
D:\home\site\repository\..\artifacts
D:\home\site\wwwroot
D:\home\site\repository
Handling node.js deployment.
before npm install
Looking for app.js/server.js under site root.
Invalid start-up command "ng serve" in package.json. Please use the format "node <script relative path>".
The package.json file does not specify node.js engine version constraints.
Missing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated
The node.js application will run with the default node.js version 10.6.0.
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
Selected npm version 6.1.0
operable program or batch file.
after npm install
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
package json exist
npm ERR! errno 1
if angular json exists
npm ERR! frontend-angular-app@0.0.0 build: `ng build --prod`
Building app in "D:\home\site\repository"
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

my package.json

```
  {
  "name": "frontend-angular-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^19.1.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^19.1.1",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng2-chartjs2": "^1.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

my build.cmd

```
 IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\package.json" (
  echo package json exist
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
  call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install --production
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  popd
)

echo after npm install



IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\angular.json" (

echo if angular json exists

  echo Building app in "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
  call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! run build

  IF !ERRORLEVEL NEQ 0 goto error
  popd
)
echo build done
:: 1. KuduSync
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%/dist" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
goto end

:: Execute command routine that will echo out when error
:ExecuteCmd
setlocal
set _CMD_=%*
call %_CMD_%
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" echo Failed exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%, command=%_CMD_%
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:error
endlocal
echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
call :exitSetErrorLevel
call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

:exitSetErrorLevel
exit /b 1

:exitFromFunction
()

:end
endlocal
echo Finished successfully.


in azure application settings 

WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION:10.6.0
```

Comment: Try using local version of `ng`. For example, instead of executing `ng run --prod` use `npm run build`

Comment: i'll give it a try

Comment: it did n't make any difference :(

Comment: try `node node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod` instead of `ng build --prod`

Comment: will update after trying @david

Comment: kudu deployment did n't work for me , used azure dev ops instead